# Wicket DefaultDataTable - Refresh it on browser back button

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicketstuff

In my application I am using DefaultDataTable with SortableDataProvider which has LoadableDetachableModel as the model.

I used it to display a set of records ( say **RecordList** page). When I add or remove some records and load the page  **RecordList** again, it displays the changes. However, if I use the back button of the browser and go the  **RecordList** page which was rentered earlier ( before adding/ removing the records ). The DefaultDataTable still has the old sets of records. This is a big issue when records are deleted.

For example, If I delete a record and press back button then the page fails as the record it is trying to show does not exist in the database.  Adding does not create an issue because it simply does not get listed in the set of records.

In another page, I just have PageableListView with LoadableDetachableModel. It works fine with out an issue.

Comment: Are you positive the back button causes a server round-trip and the browser does not cache the previous page's html?

Can you share the code of your SortableDataProvider? Are you doing any caching in that layer? Or are you using a dao layer that may cache queries?

Comment: Yes, there is a server round trip. I am not using any caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are one or two things that you can do about this.

First please check whether the data provider has the latest data.

Secondly make sure that the set of records with the Data provider is refreshed when the browser back button is hit. Ensure that the data fed to the Data Provider is refreshed in a method other than constructor.  Because constructors will not be called when you hit back. So you would need to use a separate method. Ideally you could use the same method, but called from both constructor and when back button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I will check and post it back.

Comment: Yea, the problem was with the Data provider. Cheers !